# How to break a binary image mask into multiple masks?

Tags: image-preprocessing, image-segmentation, image

[image]
I have image with binary mask. I want to break the binary mask into many individual masks of same dimension, but each mask should contain only one segmentation mask.
Is there a way to do it in python, or using libraries like pillow and open cv.

Comment: try [connected components algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) which will label each component uniquely which can then be extracted by itself

Comment: Thanks @NikosM. it was helpful.